# can any one help me to optimize my code?

Tags: python

I wrote a following code to achieve the expected results.it's working fine till 200 input.i think optimization of this code will solve my issue. Can anyone please help me to optimize the following code.

```
    from collections import defaultdict
number=input()
list_mine=[]
for i in range(1,number+1):
    list_mine.append(raw_input(""))
    #print list_mine
#understanding the number of unique occurence

unique=list(set(list_mine))

number_of_unique_occurence=len(unique)

d=defaultdict(int)
count=0
for i in unique:
    for j in list_mine:
        #print "i is "+str(i)
        if i==j:
            count = count+1
            d[i]=count

    count=0

print str(number_of_unique_occurence)
check = 0
counts =0
list_for=[]
for hel in list_mine:
     #print "current element " + str(hel)
     #print "index of that element is "+str(list_mine.index(hel))
     check = check+1

     if list_mine.index(hel) > 0:
         #print "check = " +str(check)
         for jj in range(0,list_mine.index(hel)):
             #print jj
             if hel == list_mine[jj]:
                #print "elemnt are there"
                break
             else:
                 if counts == list_mine.index(hel)-1:
                     #print "greater then zero           "+ str(hel) +"  "+str(d[hel])
                     list_for.append(d[hel])
                     continue
             counts=counts+1

     else:
         if check <= 1:
            #print "at zero              "+ str(d[hel])
            list_for.append(d[hel])


print '%s' %' '.join(map(str, list_for))
```

sample input

```
4
bcdef
abcdefg
bcde
bcdef
```

Sample output

```
3
2 1 1
```

"bcdef" appears twice in the input i.e. in the first and last position, the other words appear once each. The order of the first appearances are "bcdef", "abcdefg" and "bcde" hence the output.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask what happens at 200 input.

Comment: actually execution time getting increase .. noting much .. i never optimize my code before. i think that will some home solve the problem right ?

Comment: Did my code has any blocking element which increase the execution time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing some detail here, you are looking for the `OrderedDict` type, which lets you read out the entries of the dictionary in the order you inserted them, e.g.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
number=input()

occurrences = OrderedDict()
for i in range(1,number+1):
    s = raw_input("")
    occurrences[s] = occurrences.get(s, 0) + 1
number_of_unique_occurence=len(occurrences)
print number_of_unique_occurence
print '%s' %' '.join(map(str, occurrences.values()))
```